# MRTK Spectator View erros

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, mr-spectatorview

For my project i'm trying to add a mobile spectator to the unity game that will be played on the hololens 2. I'm trying to follow this page's instructions : [https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-SpectatorView/doc/SpectatorView.Setup.html#:~:text=HoloLens%202%20%26%20HoloLens%20as%20a%20Spectator&text=Before%20building'%20steps.-,Open%20the%20SpectatorView.,build%20settings%20and%20app%20capabilities](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-SpectatorView/doc/SpectatorView.Setup.html#:%7E:text=HoloLens%202%20%26%20HoloLens%20as%20a%20Spectator&text=Before%20building%27%20steps.-,Open%20the%20SpectatorView.,build%20settings%20and%20app%20capabilities)). However when i added the submodule via git my game gives these errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV9Nm.png) and the spectator view tab that should be visible at the top of the unity program does not exist. I'm using unity 2021.3.6f1, does anyone has an idea on how to fix these problems or overall know how to add a mobile spectator to an unity game?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For this sample, it is dependent on older components and written to target older Unity 2018.3.14f1

That is why you are seeing the errors at least when trying to use Unity 2021 with this sample.  Here is what sample states:  https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-SpectatorView/samples/README.html

Getting Started
Ensure you have all the required software, for detailed instructions see Required Software.

Git Tools
Visual Studio
Unity 2018.3.14f1

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Unfortunately i have already build my project in 2021 and will result in errors when opening in older versions of unity. Do have a idea how to still add a spectator to my game?

Comment: For the github project referenced, no support for it on Unity 2021.  So far, the community has been only successful in getting it working with Unity 2019.    Here is link on community getting it working with Unity 2019:  https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView/issues/464